# Laravel docker-compose up: Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: laravel, docker

I am facing an issue when I try to dockerize my laravel project. I use a docker-compose.yaml file and here how it looks like:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    main:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: 'php artisan migrate && php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
```

The Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer​ | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN composer install
RUN composer update
```

And this is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files":[
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I am a junior on dockers and when I run `docker-compose up` this is what I get:

[Docker error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i2bS.png)

P.S the helpers.php file works properly when I run the server locally without docker.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In you docker file you are putting all your files into docker /app

```
volumes:
    - .:/app
```

and you are not changing your directory to /app, you are changing to

```
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
```

Can you try to change your WORKDIR to /app like this:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
```